# findOne return undefined on Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to get the _id from my database, as soon as i do

```
 var test = Exemple.findOne({_id: test_id});
```

I get undefined

but when i do

```
var test = Exemple.find({}).fetch()`
```

I get all the Data of the collection,like this.

```
{ _id: '17SRlRpRSzP339E41A',
    creationIP: 'local',
    state: 
    { label: 'never connected',
    date: Wed Mar 14 2018 12:20:08 GMT+0100 (CET) },
    language: 'en',
    batch: '9zLKCkvSAyxQ4jtDG7_32018',
    creationDate: Wed Mar 14 2018 12:20:08 GMT+0100 (CET) } ]
```

i only want to get the _id and store it to a variable like this

```
var test = Exemple.findOne({_id: test_id});
```

Comment: test_id is correct? Are you putting this value: 17SRlRpRSzP339E41A?

Comment: yes sir i'm putting this value

Comment: are you using Promise? findOne is async function. try to put .exec() after the findOne
var test = Exemple.findOne({_id: test_id}).exec();

Comment: @TomMendelson  Cannot read property \'exec\' of undefined\n    at [object Object]

Comment: can you await for them? in an async function.

Comment: findOne is not async, but you have to be sure that the collection is ready. Can you post more code so we can see what is your test_id. And btw the Exemple.find({}).fetch() returns an array not the object.

Answer (score 0):

This finds the item in the database with `_id` equal to `test_id`:

```
var test_id = 'abc';
var test = Exemple.findOne({_id: test_id});
```

If no item has `_id` equal to this, it will return `null`.

To get the id of an item you can do:

```
var test = Exemple.findOne({});
var docId = test._id;
console.log(docId);
```

This will choose one random document to return however. You probably want to query for a specific item.

Answer (score -2):

```
(async function() {
const test = await Exemple.findOne({_id: test_id});
console.log(test)
})()
```

As pointed out by Tom, you have to await for promises to fulfill

Comment: I get 'ReferenceError: test  is not defined\n    at [object Object]

Comment: This is not at all accurate for Meteor